# One asp.net validator for several TextBoxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have 3 TextBoxes on the page. How do I setup **one** validator (and what's kind of validator?) to validate each of TextBoxes on client side?

First textBox must contains only 1-3 number of digits, second - infinite number of digits, third - 0-5 number of digits

Comment: You could use a CustomValidator but why don't you use three distinct validators, one for every TextBox?

Comment: I want to show only one error message at the same time.

Comment: @Alex Use Validation Summary control to show one error message. Check my answer below.

Comment: Validation Summary shows an error after postback, isn't it? But I need to show only one error message at the same time without postback.

Comment: when you say one error at a time - do you mean next to each control that's faulty - you only want to show the message against the first incorrect entry?

Comment: I want to show one generic error message. It's something like "Format is incorrect".

Comment: I see - you are validating the controls as a group?

Comment: I don't know. Is it important?

Comment: @Alex Yes it can work without postback too. Check the link on the answer for the same.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish - think I get it - see my answer.

Comment: @ Regular expression validator would solve 1st and 3rd case. Compare Validator would solve the second case. As you asked what kind of Validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use different validators for different text boxes.
Use 3 validators for each with display message as * sign.

Then use Validation Summary control to print a single message for all of them, as you want a single message to be displayed for all. Refer this link: [MSDN Validation Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Check this too: [Validation Summary to work with client-side validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857098/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-validationsummary-to-work-with-client-side-validators)

Comment: That's fine if he only has those 3 fields on the form - I'm assuming (maybe incorrectly) that he wants one message for these fields, but other fields on the form would still have their own message. In that case combining everything into one summary message would be limiting.

Comment: @BonyT As he said in the question:  one validator to validate each of TextBoxes. So he needs only 1 validator for all of the textboxes. Further in the comments of the question he says: I want to show one generic error message. It's something like "Format is incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions would be along the lines of:

[0-9]{1,3}

[0-9]+

[0-9]{0,5}

Updated following further info:

You could combine the values from each text box into a comma separated value and then validate that using [0-9]{0,3},[0-9]+,[0-9]{1,5} expression.

Either use javascript to copy the value into a hidden textbox field with it's own regex validator using above expression, or just perform the validation manually.

e.g. Using jquery

```
 $('#hiddenCombinedField').val($('#field1').val()+','+$('#field2').val()+','+$('#field3').val());
```

Run this just before you call validate on the form.

See also http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/ for some useful reference material.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but i would prefer using three distinct validators, one for every TextBox.

It's possible to leave the ControlToValidate-property of the CustomValidator empty. On this way you can validate multiple controls at the same time.