# Validation summary AutoUpdate

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application, I've tried to use validation summary in my web page.I've controls like

```
<td>First Name *</td>
<td>                                                        
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValStaffFirstName" runat="server" 
                 ErrorMessage="Enter FirstName" Text="*" 
                 ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Display="Dynamic" 
                 ValidationGroup="valGrpStaffGeneral">
         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</td>
<td>Last Name *</td> 
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValStaffLastName" runat="server" 
                 ErrorMessage="Enter LastName" Text="*" 
                 ControlToValidate="txtLastName" Display="Dynamic" 
                 ValidationGroup="valGrpStaffGeneral">
         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
     <asp:Button Id="btnSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valGrpStaffGeneral">
<td>
```

and my validationsummary script is

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="summary1" ShowSummary="true" runat="server" 
         ValidationGroup="valGrpStaffGeneral" DisplayMode="BulletList" />
```

If I click on `save` button without filling anything in textbox1 and textbox2 its showing validation errors in my validation summary area. If I fill anything in my textboxes and press tab the error(*) disappears automatically, but the error in the validation summary not changing automatically and its displaying until I click on save button, what should I do to make the validation summary change the fixed errors automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926527/update-validationsummary-list-on-control-blurs

Comment: @rt2800:can u post this in answer session?

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help - look at the `EnableClientScript` property of the `ValidationSummary` control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.enableclientscript.aspx

Comment: I just included onblur="ValidationSummaryOnSubmit()" in all the controls,its working fine, thanks for ur response Jason Evans